# Allowing Yoast SEO plugin to track me

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I've recently installed the WordPress SEO plugin by Yoast and it's asking me whether to allow it or not to track my blog? Seems like a stupid question on my part but I'm still new on the blogging arena.

What do you guys think? What's the difference if I allow it to track me or not? Is there a mutual benefit for the two of us?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For reference the file that handles the tracking and usage statistics for Yoast SEO is located at,

[`path/to/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/admin/class-tracking.php`](https://github.com/crowdfavorite/mirror-wp-wordpress-seo/blob/master/admin/class-tracking.php)

I have [linked](https://github.com/crowdfavorite/mirror-wp-wordpress-seo/blob/master/admin/class-tracking.php) to the GitHub repository file in question for further inspection upon which you can see somewhat, relatively, harmless collection of data.

However what you determine as "harmless" is case dependent because the opposite could be true if you are storing any sensitive data within the descriptive headers of plugin or themes that may be intended for internal use only.

What [information](https://github.com/crowdfavorite/mirror-wp-wordpress-seo/blob/master/admin/class-tracking.php#L76) does Yoast SEO gather about your installed themes,

```
'name' => $theme_data->display( 'Name', false, false ),
'theme_uri' => $theme_data->display( 'ThemeURI', false, false ),
'version' => $theme_data->display( 'Version', false, false ),
'author' => $theme_data->display( 'Author', false, false ),
'author_uri'=> $theme_data->display( 'AuthorURI', false, false ),
```

...and [your installed plugins](https://github.com/crowdfavorite/mirror-wp-wordpress-seo/blob/master/admin/class-tracking.php#L108),

```
'version' => $plugin_info['Version'],
'name' => $plugin_info['Name'],
'plugin_uri' => $plugin_info['PluginURI'],
'author' => $plugin_info['AuthorName'],
'author_uri' => $plugin_info['AuthorURI'],
```

...and [your site](https://github.com/crowdfavorite/mirror-wp-wordpress-seo/blob/master/admin/class-tracking.php#L118),

```
'site' => array(
'hash' => $options['hash'],
'url' => site_url(),
'name' => get_bloginfo( 'name' ),
'version' => get_bloginfo( 'version' ),
'multisite' => is_multisite(),
'users' => count( get_users() ),
'lang' => get_locale(),
),
'pts' => $pts,
'comments' => array(
'total' => $comments_count->total_comments,
'approved' => $comments_count->approved,
'spam' => $comments_count->spam,
'pings' => $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_type = 'pingback'" ),
),
```

Determine if any of that information bothers you being in the hands of another before deciding whether or not to share tracking statistics.

The tracking script [runs once per week](https://github.com/crowdfavorite/mirror-wp-wordpress-seo/blob/master/admin/class-tracking.php#L145) as per this transient.

```
set_transient( 'yoast_tracking_cache', true, 7 * 60 * 60 * 24 );
```

Will that slow down your site? No. If it does, your problems are bigger than the tracking script then ;)

The benefits of providing tracking statistics is that the information sent upstream back to the developer can be used to improve the plugin and its compatibility with other plugins and themes overall making for a better all round plugin.

*Its common practice.*

The potential downside to this is that the developer knows what themes and plugins you have installed, also, a collective of other site details as shown above.

As much as this information can be used for developmental purposes, it could also be used for marketing purposes, not so much directly, but indirectly. Is that a bad thing? Not necessarily if the intention is good for which you'd have to place some faith in Yoast not wanting to stake his reputation over something as trivial.

Comment: +1 Great writeup! Much needed dissection of the tracking code, thanks!

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks mate.. Its always worth inspecting. In this case... after doing so, I was thinking why does he need to know about my comments in that manner? And the amount of users my site has? Its interesting because I'm not drawing a correlation between those metrics, SEO and better-development which is the purpose of the tracking statistics in the first place.

Comment: @userabuser +1. I would comment on the need (or lack thereof) to phone home with these data, but such discussion would be too far off-topic. :)

Comment: @ChipBennett I sense some witty humor to be read between your lines (?) ;) ...but lack of sleep has me failing to compute, if not, do share your thoughts if you care to do so. I think its right on topic.

Comment: but the plugin would still work regardless of whether I allow it to track my blog or not?

Comment: Yep, my thoughts too about that user and comments count. I would prefer to know that beforehand and not having to dig in the code to see what exactly is being tracked. Google searching is [not revealing](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22allow+tracking%22+%2B+site:yoast.com) any official statement about it. Let us ping @JoostdeValk and see if he can offer his insights :)

Comment: Of course. Tracking is optional and in no way impacts the operation and functionality of the plugin with regards to your site. Tracking stats, or better named "usage stats" is purely for the benefit of the plugin developer as per their stated intentions (or not...) .. @brasofilo Good point, hopefully he chimes in. **Suggestion: allow users the option to toggle which statistics they want to provide.**

Comment: The user and comment counts are a reasonable way to estimate the traffic and user volume of the site without having to rely on more invasive information gathering. Remember he's only looking at counts; not personal information at all.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks, I'll agree that its a reasonable way to estimate user volume but disagree that its reasonable or even remotely reliable to estimate traffic. Even so, it still doesn't justify the reason why you need those particular metrics because by your count if he's using that as an estimation to somehow improve the plugin then the sheer lack of their accuracy (regarding traffic estimates) would be equivalent to mashing your hands on your keyboard in random succession and saying that too also improves the plugin. Can you shed some light on that in case I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: @userabuser I'd agree from a purely technical point of view that the values of user and comment counts aren't a full picture of a site when you have _all_ of the other information available. But my point is that user and comment counts are the least invasive means to provide some indication of site traffic and volume when you don't or can't have all of the site metrics. Site A that has 11 users and 3 comments total month after month can reasonably be judged to be smaller in volume than site B that adds 50 users and 200 comments each month. It's an inference of course, but not invasive.

Comment: @Stephen From a technical standpoint is all that matters when you are collecting statistics to "improve your plugin" for greater good. I own sites where the lower trafficked receive more comments than some of the higher trafficked. So reasonably judging just becomes "guessing" and again, to what end does that benefit the plugin->user relationship? It doesn't. If he is using that to gauge traffic then those metrics are purely speculative and for internal benefit to the developer unless stated otherwise. If you want to guess traffic, start with Alexa.com or Compete.com data.

Comment: @userabuser Let's agree to disagree :)

Comment: I don't know if I agree with... ha only kidding. Done.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the settings page your data is used for the future development of the plugin. I don't know what exactly the data is used for but maybe to avoid compability problems between different plugins and to integrate the plugin nicely with different themes.

> To maintain a plugin as big as WordPress SEO, we need to know what we're dealing: what kinds of other plugins our users are using, what themes, etc. Please allow us to track that data from your install. It will not track any user details, so your security and privacy are safe with us.

Comment: I see. Will it slow down my blog? I'm just paranoid. :D

Comment: @Panoy any code will slow down your blog to some extend. It's all a question of how much and in this case I'd not even worry about it unless you already have performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Every site owner should be this concerned about the information that they share with any third party. But there are a few important considerations that we must take in to account:

- What we're sharing. Well documented and outlined above by @userabuser
- Why we're sharing. Clearly stated by Yoast and quoted above by @Nicklas
- Performance impact.
- The trust factor. How well do we trust the person/company that we're sharing information with.

So from the answers we know exactly what we're sharing. It appears to me at least to be very reasonable and basic metrics about the site. And *importantly* it does not include any personal identification, so our users are safe.

We're being asked for this information to help in the improvement and future development of a great plugin.

Considering the quality of code that typically comes from this developer I'd not be overly concerned about the impact.

As far as the trust factor, well to be honest I can't think of many more highly respected and trusted WordPress developers.

So weight your own answers to these questions and make a decision that suits you.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 on that but also add that, **power corrupts, absolute power corrupts absolutely** and that's what can happen when reputation grows beyond the individual or company at hand. Not saying this is the case for Yoast, I'd think not, but I'd be less inclined to base my decision on trust, instead I would assess the individual metrics and how they align with the product and individual/company and whether or not the provider is **FOR profit** or **NOT for profit** because that often drives the intent behind the collection of certain data. Not for ill-purpose per se but for research.

Comment: Exactly why I said "So weight your own answers to these questions and make a decision that suits you.", we each have to make our own decision based on our answers and our site.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, weighed and delivered, in support of your answer so that it may provide an expanded perspective when leaning on trust, as previous performance does not always guarantee future performance. But like I said... its in support of your answer.

Comment: That's exactly how I took your comment. My response was intended to support yours as well. The 'trust' decision is a purely subjective one that each of us has to make within our own _context_ and _experience_. And your comment is certainly valid when it comes to determining the trust level.

Comment: Thanks guys. A beginner like me learned much about the discussion. Didn't expect this would lead to a good and informative one.